# Unable to resolve "../Notifications" from "node_modules\expo\build\launch\registerRootComponent.js"

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an old project and i am trying to run it but i got the error.

These are the dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.0",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-circle-slider": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-custom-checkbox": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "rn-range-slider": "^1.2.4"
  },`

my env:-

1. react-native-cli: 2.0.1
2. react-native: 0.59.8
3. expo : 3.11.1

Answer (score 3):

Delete node_modules, run `npm install`, and try again.